# Meaning of pattern in rm command

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile

I found this `rm` command in a Makefile.

`rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ $(PROG) $(INCDIR)/*~`

What is the meaning of `*~`?

Comment: It means the temporary files by some text editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*~` is not special. It matches files that end with the `~` character (often editor backup files).

Answer (score 4):

emacs is one program which leaves files ending with ~ around as backup files.  So the  creator of the makefile was probably an emacs user who wanted this target (perhaps clean?) to clean up .o files and executables and emacs droppings.

Answer (score 1):

It means all files with a `~` at the end, no matter what the other letters of the filename are. These are usually temporary files.